# On the print line it is showing syntax error...why?

Tags: python, uri

```py
def tka(A):
    
    arr=[100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
    i=0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        n=A//arr[i]
        p=A%arr[i]
        print(%n "nota (s) de R$ %d" %arr[i]",00" )
        A=p

A=int(input())
tk=tka(A)
```

Comment: What is `%n` starting the expression?

Comment: n is the variable...And in URI online judge we need to give % before the variable in print line

Comment: But `%n` is not valid syntax. What do you think it is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing :

```
print(%n "nota (s) de R$ %d" %arr[i]",00" )
```

to

```
print(f"{n} nota (s) de R$ {arr[i]},00")
```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: What error do you see? (note that you have A=int(input()) - which means when you are running the program - you need to input something) , also you need python3

Comment: syntax error...

Comment: there is no need to give input in URI online judge...and i am using python 3.9

Comment: As others asked, what does "n" do?

Comment: n is generating a integer

Comment: Ok - can you try - `print(f"{n} nota (s) de R$ {arr[i]},00")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted Python string interpolation with the percent (%) operator.

```
def tka(A):
    
    arr=[100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
    i=0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        n=A//arr[i]
        p=A%arr[i]
        print("%d nota (s) de R$ %d" % (n, arr[i]) , ",00" )
        A=p

A=int(input())
tk=tka(A)
```

Comment: its not working..i need to put the n first

Comment: @YasirKatib Which part is not working? It will print the value of `n` before `nota (s)` and so on. What is the difference from your expectation?

Comment: Its showing invalid syntax...because there is a % thing which is not corrected yet

Comment: @YasirKatib What is the complete error message?

Comment: File "/judge/judge-9310087cfc304fe88b7d2e6bd7879e8b.d/Main.py", line 8
print(%n"%d nota(s) de R$"%{arr[i]}+"00 %d")
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @YasirKatib that is not from my code. Check where you save the code or how you run the code. (also note that depending on the system, you may have have use capital M, not small m)